# Why unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog not working with unity 2018.3.14?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, user-permissions

I'm develop application with unity and vuforia and I use

```
<meta-data android:name=“unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog” android:value=“true”>
```

in Manifest.xml to skip permission on startup.My application export (apk) in unity 5.1.1 work fine but not working in untiy 2018.3.14.I'm going to create another project with unity 2018.3.14 and edit the manifest.xml with line on above, but it still ask for camera permission on startup.

This is my manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal">
    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"/>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
      <!-- For Runtime Permission -->
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog" android:value="true" />
      <activity android:name="com.onevcat.uniwebview.UniWebViewFileChooserActivity" />

    </application>  
</manifest>
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I try another way to solve problem.

1- Check the Delayed Initialization box (Window->Vuforia Configuration).

2- Use the `<meta-data android:name=“unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog” android:value=“true”>` normally and ask for permissions when I need those.

3- Add this line of code to the Start() function of this new script and assign it to empty gameobject:

```
VuforiaRuntime.Instance.InitVuforia();
```

4- So, when user allow for permission, I load 2nd Scene and it run Vuforia initialize.

Answer (score 0):

**First guess**

Unity won‘t ask for permission directly after the app start anymore, if you set `unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog`.

But Vuforia will do request a runtime permission dynamically the moment it an AR Camera is enabled.
I‘m guessing that you are using an AR Camera in you first scene?

**update 1**

Try moving `unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog` in the AndroidManifest.xml inside the activity tag instead of the application tag.

Comment: I'm using AR Camera in 2nd Scene. also my another project with unity5.1.1 work fine, Also I create empty project in unity2018.3.14 and use AR camera in 2nd Scene, but i got same problem. thanks

Comment: @Rooz Try moving unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog in the AndroidManifest.xml inside the activity tag instead of the application tag.

Comment: I Try it before post this question, but not working.Please check 
https://forum.unity.com/threads/anyway-to-stop-vuforia-asking-for-camera-permission-at-startup-android.535138/

Comment: Could you update your question with all what you already tried so far?

Comment: thank for your help. but finally i try another way to solve issue.

Comment: `update 1` saved my time. thanks so much.